# Check first X digits of IP address

Tags: c#, ip, digits

My goal is to have code execute if the local IP of the user does not start with `10.80`.

I can't find a way that isn't error prone, for example:

Here's what I have to get the I.P.:

```
        IPHostEntry host;
        string localIP = "?";
        host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
        {
            if (ip.AddressFamily.ToString() == "InterNetwork")
            {
                localIP = ip.ToString();
            }
        }
        iplabel.Text = localIP;
```

Then I attempted to convert this to an `int` to check if it's < or >:

```
string ipstring = iplabel.Text.Replace(".", "");
int ipnum = int.Parse(ipstring);
if (ipnum > 1080000000 && ipnum < 1080255255)
{//stuff}
```

But the problem is, if there is a 2 digit IP value for example `10.80.22.23` it won't work as it's checking for a number than is greater than that range.

Is there a better solution to check the first x amount of digits of an int or IP address in C#?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just use `ip.ToString().StartsWith("10.80")`?

Comment: @SteveDanner He should probably use `10.80.` (final dot) as a string, because if he is filtering for `10.1` he probably doesn't want `10.11`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
bool IsCorrectIP = ( ipstring.StartsWith("10.80.") );
```

Sorry if the answer is too terse. But that should resolve the issue at hand.

Answer (score 2):

```
byte[] bytes = ipAddress.GetAddressBytes();
bool ok = bytes.Length >= 2 && bytes[0] == 10 && bytes[1] == 80;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly check the bytes of the IP:

```
byte[] bytes = ip.GetAddressBytes();

// Check ipv4
if (ip.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork) {
    if (bytes[0] == 10 && bytes[1] == 80) {

    }
}
```

Comment: My up vote is for showing the OP how to correctly compare an enum.

Answer (score 0):

@Flater is quite true. You can additionally use this

```
bool IsCorrectIP = false;
string[] iparr = ipstring.Split(new char[] { '.' ,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries });
if(iparr[0] = "10" && iparr[1] == 80)
{    
    IsCorrectIP = true;
}
```

But even I'd go for the @Flater's solution :)

Comment: That was my original suggestion, until I though about StartsWith :) Just as valid as my answer afaik (maybe slight performance difference?).